design a +24 volt dc power supply using bridge rectifier circuit
Q5. Design a + 24 volt DC power supply using bridge rectifier circuit.
Instruction:

Draw the neat block and schematic diagram of the designed dc power supply system

Determine the required components specification

Sketch the appropriate wave form of each stage of the circuit

Write a brief note how the circuit works

Practically test the system in the laboratory



For homework questions like this, to help you we need to know what you have tried and where you are stuck.

I’m voting to close this question because it's homework with no attempt at a solution.

Alia Abdulkadir - Hi, That looks like a copy of your assignment. But we need to see your own work first & your specific question. Those are currently missing, so your question has been "closed". However as explained in that link, it will be put in a queue to consider re-opening it, if you [Edit] your question, add your own genuine best solution attempt, all of your analysis & make it clear exactly where you're stuck. || Questions which just copy coursework to us, without showing your own work, are not well-received. || See [tour] & [help] for main site rules. TY
